# Custom Array Sorting by input string and position

Tags: php, sorting, ksort

I have an array. It' looks like:

```
$arr = [
   '0' => ['id'=>9, 'q'=>'motor', 'pos'=>1],
   '1' => ['id'=>10, 'q'=>'NULL', 'pos'=>0],
   '2' => ['id'=>7, 'q'=>'motor', 'pos'=>2],
   '3' => ['id'=>8, 'q'=>'NULL',  'pos'=>0],
   '4' => ['id'=>11, 'q'=>'motor','pos'=>3],
   '5' => ['id'=>11, 'q'=>'exhaust','pos'=>1]
];
```

How can I sort the data above to make it looks like (if q='motor' is inside search string):

```
 $arr = [
       '0' => ['id'=>9, 'q'=>'motor', 'pos'=>1],
       '2' => ['id'=>7, 'q'=>'motor', 'pos'=>2],
       '4' => ['id'=>11, 'q'=>'motor','pos'=>3],
       '1' => ['id'=>10, 'q'=>'NULL', 'pos'=>0],
       '3' => ['id'=>8, 'q'=>'NULL',  'pos'=>0],
       '5' => ['id'=>11, 'q'=>'exhaust','pos'=>1]
    ];
```

So:

```
function custom_sort($input_query, $arr) {
   foreach($arr as $key=>$row) {
      if (strpos($input_query, $row['q'])) {
          ... How to Sort By Pos?
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks!

**Updated (question/answer)**
*p.s: I'm trying to use custom variable as input: $q*

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($q) {
        if ($a['q'] == $q) {
            if($b['q'] == $q) {
                return ($a['pos'] > $b['pos']) ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if ($b['q'] == $q) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

And the function stop working. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does the position of the others elements != motor should be considered?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `usort` that handles your requirements, wrapped in a function that transforms the array in place:

1. Items with `q` key containing `$query` will be placed at the front of the array.
2. Items with `q` key containing `$query` will be sorted ascending by their `pos` value.
3. Everything else will be sorted by its `pos` value.

```
function custom_sort($query, &$arr) {
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($query) {
        $in_a = strpos($a['q'], $query) !== false;
        $in_b = strpos($b['q'], $query) !== false;

        if ($in_a && !$in_b) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!$in_a && $in_b) {
            return 1;
        }

        return $a['pos'] - $b['pos'];
    });
}

custom_sort("motor", $arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort`

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['q'] == 'motor') {
        if($b['q'] == 'motor') {
            return ($a['pos'] > $b['pos']) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if ($b['q'] == 'motor') {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

If you need a different order, just change the function to match your needs.

Comment: Works great, but the index ids at the beginning were reset. If they are insignificant for the task I would consider it answered.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to use something like this: usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($q) { -> and replace 'motor' to $q. And the function above -> stop working.

Answer (score 1):

U sort would help you here

```
usort( $arr, function ( $a, $b ) {
    if ( $a['q'] === $b['q'] ) {
        return $a['pos'] < $b['pos'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if ( $a['q'] === 'motor' ) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( $b['q'] === 'motor' ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
} );
```

Comment: Isn't it rude to adapt someone else's answer without making a reference to it?

Comment: @Rafael we posted about the same time. Thanks for assuming I just stole his answerr, even though I didnt. he does not account for 'pos' as OP requested.

Comment: @Ice76, I assumed that because of the variables and returns, but ok, one shall not assume other stole an answer without proof, and I apologize. Answer does not provide what OP wanted though. Result is not ordered as his sample.

Comment: Made the change, I made the mistake of returning -1 when `$b` was a motor. I fixed it, and now it returns as I initially expected

Comment: Apparently everyone likes $a, $b variables. :)

Comment: @Rafael almost all custom comparators use `$a` and `$b`. I don't see any plagiarism going on here if that's what you're suggesting, although at this point everyone's answers are in fact pretty much the same.

Comment: Seems like it is settled though. I do use `$a` and `$b` quite often though. I think that those var's are too short to make a correlation, too. But nevertheless, sorted!

Comment: The variables were just one of the hints, position of the returns, position of the ifs, variables evaluated. If it was only for the variables I wouldn't consider it anything. But a closure that looks pretty much the same, raise suspicions. But well, what does it matter anyway? Everyone's answer is working. I would just choose the first one posted.

Comment: Everything good. I'm just trying to replace 'motor' to input variable. And it's not the easiest part...